# StackSurfer iOS App

Tags: app, search, iphone, ios

### StackSurfer Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

### About

**“StackSurfer – Search Faster, Work Smarter”**

StackSurfer provides a smarter way to search for questions and answers in Stack Overflow. You can search for questions regarding programming, design patterns, operating systems and just about anything to do with software or hardware.

**KEY FEATURES**

1. Faster and efficient search interface.
2. Easily sort questions based on Relevance,Votes,Creation date and User activity.
3. Save favorite answers to Notes.
4. Access Notes anywhere, anytime using iCloud.
5. Share notes with friends.
6. Toggle settings to hide down-voted answers and questions.
7. Toggle settings to sort answers by Votes and dates.

#### License

The app is free to download from Apple App Store and provides In-App Purchases.

#### Download

1. **Website:** https://apps.apple.com/au/app/stack-surfer/id1192552794

#### Platform

iOS

### Contact

This app was created by SlickClickStudios. Visit our website **(https://apps.apple.com/au/app/stack-surfer/id1192552794)** for more information. So get in touch via stacksurfer@gmail.com **(mailto: stacksurfer@gmail.com)**.

**Twitter: @KarkeraSunil.**

### Code

This iOS app has been programmed in Swift.